# How to calculate a citric acid and trisodium citrate buffer?

Tags: acid-base, equilibrium, buffer, henderson-hasselbalch-equation

I am trying to calculate how to prepare 500 mL of a citric acid (H3Cit) and trisodium citrate (Na3Cit) buffer with a pH = 4.5 and a total concentration of 0.1 M. I know that it is necessary to use the Henderson Hasselbalch equation but I don't quite understand how to perform the calculation, taking into account that at that pH there are several species of the citrate anion present and that citric acid first dissociates into citrate anion in the form H2Cit(1-). I found in this forum an equation, which I think I could use:

[How do I calculate the amount of polyprotic acid and base needed to achieve a certain buffer pH?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/100886/how-do-i-calculate-the-amount-of-polyprotic-acid-and-base-needed-to-achieve-a-ce)

However I don't understand how to get that equation. Can someone explain to me, please? Thank you

Comment: See here: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/116226/79678. From the alpha fractions in my answer at the link, you see that at pH 4.5 you have the hydrogen citrate ion and the dihydrogen citrate ion. Citric acid and citrate ion are negligible at that pH. So one citric acid plus one citrate ion yields one each of the two other species.

Comment: Is it a computation exercise, or a practical task? If the latter, why not to use e.g  [Sigma-Aldrich citric acid pH buffer preparations table](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/CZ/en/technical-documents/protocol/protein-biology/protein-concentration-and-buffer-exchange/buffer-reference-center) ?